# Deployment error in netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee

while running java programme in Netbeans I am getting error

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
debug:
Starting of Tomcat failed, the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\catalina.bat startup script is missing.
E:\project\demo1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:771: Starting of Tomcat failed, the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\catalina.bat startup script is missing.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please give me solution for this.

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\catalina.bat` really exist?

Comment: @zvzdhk I checked it now ,there is no such script file but my question is how to add this file

Comment: It should be there, try to reinstall Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I had the same problem today and the answer didn't help.

The tomcat download page has a **"windows service installer"** and a **"windows zip"**, the service installer does not installs the catalina.bat script, you **should use zip installer**.

You should not forget to **configure your tomcat**, read **RUNNING.txt**.

Answer (score 0):

remove "Use custom Catalina script" check box in "Startup" tab in server properties window.

actually

1 - select Servers in Services tab

2 - Right click in your Apache Tomcat 7.X.X

3 - select "Startup" tab

4 - remove "Use custom Catalina script" check box

5 - press run button